# Problems creating Trigger ORA-00942

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert, oracle11g, ora-00942

I'm trying to create a trigger that should verify a new input value for 'grado_academico' when I insert into 'Investigadores' that is in 'director' schema and in another tablespace.

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE director.Investigadores (
id_investigador numeric(6, 0) NOT NULL,
 nombre varchar(40)  NOT NULL, apellido_pat varchar(40)  NOT NULL,
 apellido_mat varchar(40)  NOT NULL, grado_academico varchar(40)  NOT NULL, 
 fecha_ingreso date NOT NULL,  nivel_sni numeric(2, 0) NOT NULL,  
 CONSTRAINT id_investigador  PRIMARY KEY (id_investigador)) 
 tablespace sni_tablespace;
```

and this is my trigger

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verificarGrado
        before insert on director.Investigadores 
        for each row
        begin
            IF (new.grado_academico='MC' OR new.grado_academico='DOCTOR' OR new.grado_academico='LICENCIATURA')
                return new;
            else
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'El grado academico solo puede ser MC, DOCTOR o LICENCIATURA';
            end if;
        END;
/
```

But when i created the trigger returns me a warning, so I run

```
SQL> show errors
ERROR:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

So why it returns me this warning if my table already exist? 
is my trigger incorrectly? 
My user 'director' has privileges to create any trigger. 
Should I do something more? 
Please I hope you could help me with this issue.

**EDIT**

I changed my trigger using the schema

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER director.verificarGrado
before insert on director.Investigadores
for each row
begin
    IF (:new.grado_academico='MC' OR :new.grado_academico='DOCTOR' OR :new.grado_academico='LICENCIATURA')
    then
            :new.grado_academico:=:new.grado_academico; 
    else
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'El grado academico solo puede ser MC, DOCTOR o LICENCIATURA';
    end if;
END;/
```

Throws me the same error.

The line :new.grado_academico:=:new.grado_academico;  is where I'm not sure what i suppossed to do, i just need that the insertion keeps going

**EDIT**
I changed the logic for my conditional I'm using IF NOT ... thank you for that recommendation

Anyways, It looks it's a issue about privileges, I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you creating the trigger in the "director" schema?  You also have a syntax error, as "new" should be ":new".  ALso, you cannot "return" a value from a trigger.

Comment: It try it with CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER director.Investigadores and it doesn't work, I'll check the syntax again and make corrections, thank you @OldProgrammer.

Comment: Then just change the condition logic to, IF NOT ... then raise ...

Comment: The ORA-00942 simply means the account under which you are trying to create the trigger cannot see the table. Do a `SELECT FROM director.Investigadores;`

Comment: Hi @JeffreyKemp, I try it and it works (recently I insert some values into the table) I can see the rows, and I logged 'director as sysdba'